# python: writing a wrapper around a third-party class

Tags: python, design-patterns, interface, wrapper

I need some functionality from a class X of a third-party module m. I could just use m.X directly, but I may need to replace m.X with another class n.Y in the future (e.g., if I discover a better implementation).

I'd like to avoid changing the rest of the code in such a situation.

For now, I want the full interface of m.X, including initialization, to pass through unchanged. I wrote a wrapper W for m.X as follows:

```
class W(m.X):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
```

In the future, should the need arise, I plan to rewrite the above as:

```
class W(n.Y):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
    # override instance methods of n.Y that don't share the semantics with m.X
    # for example, in case f1 is hard to replicate in n.Y:
    # def f1(self, *args):
    #     print("this method is no longer available")
    #     raise MyDeprecatedMethod()
    # for example, in case f2 needs to be recalculated
    # def f2(self, *args):
          # do the calculations required to keep W.f2 unchanged
```

Is my current wrapper for m.X acceptable? Are there are problems with it, or with the planned wrapper for n.Y?

Comment: Looks good to me (at least, this is how I do it)

Comment: How much wrapping do you really need? If the only problem is shielding the rest of the code from a potential change in naming, then simply `W = m.X` should suffice, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method is to write:

```
W = m.X
```

Practically everything in Python is a first-class object - including types. A class is almost indistinguishable from any other variable, for example:

```
def W(*args, **kwargs):
    return m.X(*args, **kwargs)
```

can instantiate an instance of m.X while appearing that W is the actual name of it. (Note that with this method `isinstance` will not work correctly - it *will* work fine with the first example.)

In some cases, using assignment may not play nicely with IDEs. In this case:

```
class W(m.X): pass
```

will also produce the same result, though with the added overhead in that instances of `W` are only instances of `m.X` because `W` is a subclass: using `W=m.X; W(args)`  will create an instance of `m.X`.

Comment: And if the OP wants to override a changed function they can do `def myFun(self, *args): doSomething()` and `W.f1 = myFun; W.f2 = myFun` etc.

Comment: @Fantasizer That will work, but will also apply to `m.X`. Overriding functions is best done by creating a new class and overriding just the required method (no need to do `__init__` unless it's changing).

Answer (score 3):

You could simply use

```
class W(m.X):
    pass
```

which inherits `m.X.__init__()` by default.

Answer (score 0):

This would depend on how different m.X and n.Y are in their methods you're using, but it could be as simple as

```
try:
    import n.Y as foo
except ImportError:
    import m.X as foo

class W(foo):
    pass
```

so your code reflects the new module automatically, potentially minimizing the changes you need to make throughout your codebase.